# control div in full screen mode

Tags: html

```
<body style="margin: 0pt auto;">
<div id="header" style="background-color:#000033; width:auto; height:70px"></div>
<div id="body" style="background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); width: 100%; position: absolute; margin-right: 300px; margin-left: -300px; height: 76%;"></div>
<div id="nav" style="position: absolute; left: 1066px; width: 300px; top: 70px; height: 76%; background-color: rgb(221, 34, 221);"></div>
<div id="footer" style="background-color:#000033; width:100%; height:70px; position:absolute; bottom:0"></div>
</body>
```

****Full Screen View****

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VukrD.jpg

how can remove white space when we are in full screen mode? like **normal view** as follow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhtwT.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The white gap is there because you can't guarantee that `70px + 76% + 70px == 100%`. In fact, chances are it doesn't, and you just got that `76%` value because you tried different numbers until it fit.

Since they are absolute-position elements, try using `bottom: 70px;` instead of the height.